# Argument parser for a word count and/or line count program

Tags: python, python-2.7

How to make code dry in this example? 
The print words and lines are repeating..

```
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--words', '-w', action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('--lines', '-l', action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('filename')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.words:
        print "Words in a file: {}" .format(print_words(args.filename))

    elif args.lines:
        print "Lines in a file: {}" .format(print_lines(args.filename))

    else:
        print "Words in a file: {}" .format(print_words(args.filename))
        print "Lines in a file: {}" .format(print_lines(args.filename))
```

I guess by adding a new function and putting the function call in the else statement.

I tried with the print_all function, I added the function call in the else statement.

```
def print_all(filename, args):
    for a in read_file(filename):
        if a in args:
            print "All word counts :", a
```

When I run the program using the print_all function I get:

> Namaspace(words=False, filename='someFile.txt', lines=False)

Comment: I suggest a dehumidifier.

Comment: If this is **working code** that you think could be improved, consider [codereview.se] (@MorganThrapp: boom)

Comment: yes this is a working code, that I wont to improve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a simple additional condition to return true when both flags are false and removing the elif should do what you want:

```
if args.words or not arg.lines:
    print "Words in a file: {}" .format(print_words(args.filename))

if args.lines or not arg.words:
    print "Lines in a file: {}" .format(print_lines(args.filename))
```

To extend to multiple conditions you may want to check out this post [python argparse set behaviour when no arguments provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14358753/python-argparse-set-behaviour-when-no-arguments-provided)

Comment: This looks good. How would I write this code if I had more if statemnts? 5 more

Answer (score 3):

Your flags are slightly misleading, simply have the flag be true if you want it to be printed.

```
if args.words:
    print "Words in a file: {}" .format(print_words(args.filename))

if args.lines:
    print "Lines in a file: {}" .format(print_lines(args.filename))
```