# Python argpass: don't require positional arguments when certain options are specified

Tags: python, argparse

Positional parameters with `nargs='+'` or `nargs=<integer>` are required, meaning that `argparse` gives an error if the parameter is not specified at least once. However, no error is given if the user calls the program with the `-h|--help` option, regardless of whether the positional parameters were specified.

**How can I implement custom options like `-h` that do not require positional parameters to be set, while still requiring positional parameters for all other options?**

For example, if let's say my program has the following (or similar) usage text:

```
usage: PROG [-h] [-o] [-u] positional
```

How can I implement the following behaviour:

- calling `PROG` with no options and no positionals is an error
- calling `PROG` with `-u` and no positionals is an error
- calling `PROG` with only positionals is allowed
- calling `PROG` with `-h` or `-o` is allowed regardless of whatever else is specified

## My code

This meets all requirements except the last one, namely `-o` still requires the positional parameter to be specified.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('positional', nargs=1)
parser.add_argument('-o', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('-u', action='store_true')

args = parser.parse_args()

print(args)
```

Does `argparse` have a built-in way to say that `positional` is not required **iff** `-o` is specified, or must this behaviour be implemented manually?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#mutual-exclusion works with one positional (? or *).  For fancier interactions you'll need to do your own testing after parsing.  Before imposing complex requirements on your users, think about how you'll explain them.  Ideally the single `usage` line should encode all such requirements.

Comment: When using `nargs='?'` or '*' for positionals, it's a good idea to specify a `default` parameter.

Comment: Consider making '-u' a plain `store`, taking a value.  That could simplify the requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Manual methods

Set `nargs='?'` or `nargs='*'` for the positional parameter (i.e. make it optional), and then add the following lines immediately after `args = parser.parse_args()`:

```
if not args.o and args.positional is None:
    parser.error("the following arguments are required: positional")
```

Or add these lines, courtesy of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42656974/4421959):

```
if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    # display help message when no args are passed.
    parser.print_help()
    sys.exit(1)
```

This simply prints the help message if no options or positional parameters were specified. This behaviour is consistent with many command line programs, e.g. `git`.

Of course, making `positional` optional will affect the usage message:

```
usage: PROG [-h] [-o] [-u] [positional]
```

If you really don't want this to happen you can override the usage method like this:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(usage="%(prog)s [-h] [-o] [-u] positional")
```